# How to import Gwt-Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, gwt, uibinder

I will use Gwt-Bootstrap in my UiBinder files. I imported this

```
xmlns:b="urn:import:com.github.gwtbootstrap.client.ui">
```

to my UIBinder file and this

```
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{your module name}/css/font-awesome-ie7.css">
```

to my Html file. But it doesnt work. The Error is

```
Package com.github.gwtbootstrap.client.ui cannot be 
 resolved
```

Answer (score 1):

GWT-Bootstrap must be added to the GWT project. If you are using Maven, add the respective dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.gwtbootstrap</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-bootstrap</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, inherit the GWT-Bootstrap module in your GWT module (< YourProject >.gwt.xml):

```
<module>
    <inherits name='com.github.gwtbootstrap.Bootstrap' />
    ...
</module>
```

However, please notice that GWT-Bootstrap is outdated and no longer maintained. I use Bootstrap and GWT on many projects and I believe the best way to use it together is using HTML and Bootstrap standards and binding the HTML elements with Elemental2 to GWT. It works great, there are no limitations and it is future-proof.

Comment: it doesnt work. But how do you use bootstrap,html and gwt? Can you explain this?

Comment: Did you forget to add GWT-Bootstrap to your project? I have edited my answer. If it answers your question, please accept this answer.

Comment: You should give Domino-UI a try: https://github.com/DominoKit/domino-ui